# Unit testing vue component containing vuetify

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js

For example, how to trigger a change event in v-autocomplete inside your component, so that I

I tried something like:

```js
import SomethingAutocomplete from "@/components/SomethingAutocomplete.vue";
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import { VAutocomplete } from "vuetify/lib";
import { Constructor } from "vue/types/options";

test("Some test", async () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(SomethingAutocomplete);
  let ac = wrapper.find(<Constructor>VAutocomplete);
  ac.trigger("input");
  await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
  ...
  <handler was never called>
});
```

Any hints? TIA.

Comment: input is an event. I suppose you want to capture it inside a parent component. Did you try `ac.vm.$emit("input", valueOfTheInput);` instead of `ac.trigger("input");` ?

Comment: Also it is written `trigger("input")` in your code but you write "a change event" in your explanation. What event is it exactly ?

Comment: ac.vm.$emit("change") worked! sorry for the mix up in the example i wrote on the post. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trigger()` is only used to trigger event inside the component. Since here we want to check the behaviour on an event emitted by a child, we need to emit the event to the parent component.
So this will do the job :

```
ac.vm.$emit("input", valueOfTheInput);
```